# How do you replace AND update in PHP using preg_replace (or similar)?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to loop through an array converting specific key/value pairs that contain markup to HTML.

So an example value for $comment['comment_text'] would be:

```
This has *bolded* text
```

And should become:

```
This has <strong>bolded</strong> text
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
$pattern = "/\*\b.*?\b\*/i";
$newComment = preg_replace($pattern, "<strong>$&</strong>", 
$comment['comment_text']);
```

And what I get:

> This has **$&** text

I realize I'm mashing up Javascript with PHP, but reading about back references in PHP hasn't made things any clearer.

My strings may have multiple bolded (in markup) instances...

Any help appreciated.

UPDATE:
Apologies - I didn't realize that Stackoverflow was converting asterisks to italics. I converted the example to code.

Also, my confusion came down to the use of $0 vs. $1. Which I still don't fully understand. I thought the numbers referred to the matches in the string...so if you had 5 instances you could refer to them by $0 through $4.

If you use $0 you get:

```
This has <strong>*bolded*</strong> text
```

But if you use $1 you get the desired result.

Comment: Add to your question the exact value of `$comment['comment_text']` so we can reproduce and test.

Comment: I tried your code assuming `$comment['comment_text'] = "This has bolded text";` and I get **This is bolded text**.  So unless you provide an [mcve] question, we will not be able to help further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this.

```
 $pattern = "/\*\b(.*?)\b\*/";
 $newComment = preg_replace($pattern, "<strong>$1</strong>", $comment['comment_text']);
```

Here `$1` refers to the group 1 match. Here I'm supposing that you want to make text between `**` bolded.

Comment: Stating he had "no idea" is incorrect. I wasn't that clear...but he read between the lines and provided a correct answer. An explanation would have been great - the key is the $1.